# I want an input text area to accept up to 150 characters but it should not accept only hyphen (-) or dot (.)

Tags: regex

I want an input text area to accept up to 150 characters including alpha-numeric and special characters, but it should not accept only special characters alone. Does anyone know the regular expression for this?

Comment: @ryekayo he also asked for special characters.

Comment: Your wording is confusing.  "it should not accept only special characters alone"?  What does this mean?  It can accept special characters, but only if they are not the only characters in the string?

Comment: Also, what exactly is a "special character"? Only dot and hyphen?

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to match strings with obligatory letters or numbers, you can use:

```
^(?![^a-zA-Z0-9]*$)[^.-]{150}$
```

Here is an [example](https://regex101.com/r/wR6wV1/1). The 2nd line is not matched as it only contains special characters.

Comment: it does not match any string starting/ending with a special character

Comment: However, it also accepts lots of other characters besides alnum, dot and hyphen. The question is ambiguous, though - OP needs to clarify.

Comment: @stribizhev duhhh I was adding a special character exceeding the maxlength sry